# Coding a simple parking fee calculator using only C functions

Tags: c, function, calculator

I have been given the following assignment:

> Write a function (documentation included) that given the entry and the
>   exit time of a vehicle in a parking lot, and the hourly rate,
>   calculates the amount due.
>
> Assumptions:
>
> 1. no overnight parking
> 2. there is no charge for part of an hour
> 3. the time is given in military style (1:20p.m. is 1320)
>
> You also have to write a test-driver for your function:  in main()
>   declare and initialize as many variables as needed,  then call the
>   function and display the amount.

This is the code:

```
int calcRate (int entry , int exit);

int main (void)
{
    // Local Declarations
    int entry;
    int exit;

    //Statements
    printf("Please Enter Entry and Exit time(In military style. For example : 9.30am as
           0930)\n");
    scanf("%d %d\n",&entry , &exit);

    double fee = calcRate(entry,exit);

    printf("Your Parking Fees are %f\n", fee);

    return 0;
}   //main

/*==============calcRate================
 This function calculates the cost of parking
 */

double calcRate (int entry,int exit,double cost)
{
    int hours;
    double rate = 2.00;
    //Statements
    hours = (exit-entry)/100;
    cost = hours * rate;

    return (cost);
}
//calcRate
```

I cannot build it and I am facing problems with it. For example, I get the following error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "calcRate(int, int)", referenced from: _main in Parking.o (maybe you meant: calcRate(int, int, double)

I'm stuck for almost 2 hours now.
Any kind souls out there?

Comment: facing problems? what problems?

Comment: See the declaration and definition of "calcRate" function. This code would not even compile.

Comment: i cant build it.

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "calcRate(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in Parking.o
     (maybe you meant: calcRate(int, int, double))

Comment: you do not need to pass the parameter "double cost" where you have defined "calcRate". Just declare the double cost inside the calcRate function.

Comment: i did that. but my prof wants me to declare it in the function header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difference between function declaration and definition

Function Declarations

```
int calcRate (int entry , int exit);
```

Definition header

```
double calcRate (int entry,int exit,double cost)
```

So either change Declaration  or definition header

for Eg: 
Change definition header to

```
int calcRate(int entry,int exit)
```

and add declare

```
double cost
```

within  function calcRate.

Instead of

```
  printf("Please Enter Entry and Exit time(In military style. For example : 9.30am as 0930)\n");
  scanf("%d %d\n",&entry , &exit);
```

Do

```
 printf("Please Enter Entry (In military style. For example : 9.30am as 0930)\n");
 scanf("%d",&entry);
 printf("\n Please exit Entry (In military style. For example : 9.30am as 0930)\n");  
 scanf("%d",&exit);
```

No "\n" within scan.

**EDIT:**

In case of overnightparking

Instead of

```
hours = (exit-entry)/100;
```

use

```
if(exit>entry)
    hours = (exit-entry)/100;
else
    {
        int overnightHours;
        overnightHours = (entry-exit)/100;
        hours=2400-overnightHours;
    }
```

This  will remove negative value.

Comment: im facing the same problem. once i input entry time,it goes to a new line and i've got to enter something before i can get to input exit time.

Comment: Always ensure exit time is higher than entry for eg if entry time = 0700 then exit time  should greater than 0700. If Exit time always greater than exit time. then you wont get negative value

Comment: if i could use if/else would have just used it in main and finished this problem.
prof wants me to use simple functions. THANKS ANW.

Comment: Pardon, i couldn't get what you mean. :):)

Comment: If else is not a function , it is simplest condition operator in C. :):) .Please check the logic as Entry will only become greater than exit in conditions like Entry time=23.00 and exit time =0200 .So in that case you may have to change program a little. Enjoy codding

Comment: Edited code will work fine even in conditions having overnight parking

Comment: i cannot use if/else for this program.

Comment: If no overnight parking then there wont be the  condition (Entry time>Exit time). So old program will work fine. So no need of if/else.  If you want to add "cost" to definition and declaration. Use code given below by @Abhineet. It is using pointers, which is little higher concept in c. Check with professor if pointers are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
#include <stdio.h>

void calcRate (int entry , int exit, double *cost);

int main (void)
{
    int entry;
    int exit;
    double cost=0 ;

    printf("Please Enter Entry time(In military style. For example : 9.30am as 0930)\n");
    scanf("%d", &entry);
    printf("Please Enter Exit time(In military style. For example : 9.30am as 0930)\n");
    scanf("%d", &exit);

    calcRate(entry,exit,&cost);
    printf("Your Parking Fee is %lf\n", cost);
    return 0;
}   

void calcRate (int entry , int exit, double *cost)
{
    double hours;
    double rate = 2.00;

    hours = (double)(exit-entry)/100 ; //you need to convert your HRS correctly, ex-     entry=0930, exit=1000. cost should be 1.000 but your code will print 1.4000
    *cost = hours * rate;
}
```

Comment: Program builds and runs.

requires me to input 3 times and fee is negative.

Answer (score 0):

```
int calcRate (int entry , int exit);

int main (void)
{
// Local Declarations
int entry;
int exit;

//Statements
printf("Please Enter Entry time (In military style :  0930)\n");
scanf("%d",&entry);

printf("Please Enter Exit time (In military style :  0930)\n");
scanf("%d"&exit);
```

Also no `\n` is required in `scanf()`

```
double fee = calcRate(entry,exit);

printf("Your Parking Fees are %lf\n", fee);
```

needs `%lf` because fee is `double`

```
return 0;
}  

double calcRate (int entry,int exit)
{
double cost;
double hours;
double rate = 2.00;
//Statements
hours = ((double)(exit-entry))/100;
```

Here you have done `integer division` which may cause error.
So make hours as `double`.

```
cost = hours * rate;

return cost;

}
```

Comment: I think .. this might help you ..there are many little bugs in your code

Comment: how ? have you tried `%lf` for double ..because mismatch of % specifier and argument in printf is undefined behaviour